# How to get HTML XPath copied from a web browser developer console to play nicely with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am writing a program that scrubs HTML from web pages using XPath. I am designing it to be configurable so that you can enter node XPaths that you copy straight from a browsers dev console as shown in pic, but I am encountering an issue that makes this seemingly impossible. Both Brave (Chromium) and Firefox add `tbody` nodes that don't exist in the original document, so, when I use .NET code to get the HTML from the server, it doesn't match up with what's rendered by the browser. When I copy the node's XPath from the browser's dev console and pass it into `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode`, it fails to locate the node.

Does HtmlAgilityPack have a means to play nicely with this disparity or do I have to write some code that iterates through programmatically-generated variants of the original XPath entered into my program?

[image]

Comment: IMO, absolute XPath generated by browser dev console - it is something you shouldn't use at all :) never ever

Comment: @JaSON I am working on creating an XPath resolver that searches the HTML based on various criteria and provides the XPath of the node you select. I will then enter that XPath into the program. I have a feeling there isn't a better way

Comment: Writing some code to remove the `tbody`part once the XPath is provided is probably the best option.`//table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]` >>> `//table[1]//tr[1]/th[1]`

Comment: I've considered this, but the snag is that the developers could actually add server-side `tbody` tags, so, if I removed them, the search would fail. I'd have to do two attempts, one with `tbody` and one without. It's not a huge performance hit, but I was really hoping there's a way for HtmlAgilityPack to resolve this in some way. In the meantime, I did what I said above which is create an XPath resolver that lets you search for an element and then get its XPath.